# Can I relative-copy files in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a directory structure like this:

```
a
  /one
    hey.class
    hey.tasty
    you.class
    you.tasty
  /two
    foo.class
    foo.tasty
    /three
      bar.class
      bar.tasty

b 
  /one
  /two
    /three
```

I need a way to copy all the .tasty files from their respective places in /a to their corresponding places in /b in a sbt task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the sbt task and pass the original and destination folders in the following manner:

```
val copyTasties = inputKey[Unit]("Copy .tasty files")

copyTasties := {
  val userInput = Def.spaceDelimited().parsed
  if (userInput.size != 2) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Original and target directories should be define!")
  }
  val from = Paths.get(userInput.head)
  val to = Paths.get(userInput.last)

  Files
    .walk(from)
    .filter(Files.isRegularFile(_))
    .filter(path => path.toString.endsWith("tasty"))
    .forEach { original =>
      val relative = from.relativize(original)
      val destination = to.resolve(relative)
      IO.copyFile(original.toFile, destination.toFile)
    }
}
```

Then you can invoke it like this:

```
copyTasties C:\\Dev\\sandbox\\a C:\\Dev\\sandbox\\b
```

If the original and destination are stable(for example they are directories inside the project) you can rewrite the task:

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

import sbt._

val copyTastiesHardcoded = taskKey[Unit]("Copy .tasty files")

copyTastiesHardcoded := {
  val baseDir = baseDirectory.value.toPath

  val from = baseDir.resolve("a")
  val to = baseDir.resolve("b")

  Files
    .walk(from)
    .filter(Files.isRegularFile(_))
    .filter(path => path.toString.endsWith("tasty"))
    .forEach { original =>
      val relative = from.relativize(original)
      val destination = to.resolve(relative)
      IO.copyFile(original.toFile, destination.toFile)
    }
}
```

and invoke it without arguments

```
copyTastiesHardcoded
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful utility methods in sbt that will help you find files and copy them around. Unfortunately the use a wild mixture of the traditional `java.io.File` and the more modern `java.nio.file.Path`, so you need to do conversions between them:

```scala
val copyFiles = taskKey[Unit]("copy files")
copyFiles := {
  val inputDir = baseDirectory.value.toPath / "a"
  val files: Seq[(Path, FileAttributes)] =
    FileTreeView.default.list(inputDir.toGlob / RecursiveGlob / "*.tasty")
  val outputDir = baseDirectory.value.toPath / "b"
  IO.copy {
    files.map { case (p, _) =>
      p.toFile -> outputDir.resolve(inputDir.relativize(p)).toFile
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I'm using a glob here to find the files:
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Globs.html